# rust function return from within a nested iterator

Tags: function, rust, return

Note:

- The original question was poorly phrased. I was looking for something that would allow a simple return which is not what `std::array::try_from_fn` does. I did not understand that at the time.
- there is some excellent discussion on alternatives and solutions stopgaps to use while we wait for `std::array::try_from_fn` to be stabilised. (these may come with a performance hit but that will likely be optimised away by the compiler)

I have a function which creates a sudoku grid from a 9 by 9 grid of numbers. If an invalid number is found it is supposed to return with information on where that number is (the functionality for which is within the commented out code). The code currently runs but if the commented out code is used to replace the `.unwrap()` then the compiler spits out a range of errors which (if I'm interpreting correctly) show that the `return` is returning the values to `std::array::from_fn` rather than from `unsolved_sudoku_from_nums`. How can I fix this to work as intended? Thanks,

```
/// parse nums into an UnsovedSudoku, 1-9 will be parsed as values 1-9, 0 will be parsed as an unsolved cell and all
///  other values will cause the function to return an InvalidInt error.
fn unsolved_sudoku_from_nums(nums: &[[u8; 9]; 9]) -> Result<UnsolvedSudoku, InvalidInt> {
    Ok(UnsolvedSudoku (
        std::array::from_fn(|i|{
            std::array::from_fn(|j| {
                match nums[i][j] {
                    0 => WorkingCell::PossibleValues([true; 9]),
                    int => WorkingCell::Solved(
                        SudokuValue::from_int(int)
                            .unwrap()
                            // .expect(
                            //     return Err(InvalidInt{
                            //         row: i, 
                            //         column: j, 
                            //         int: nums[i][j],
                            //     })
                            // )
                        ),
                }
            })
        })
    ))
}
```

FYI

```
struct UnsolvedSudoku (
    [[WorkingCell; 9]; 9]
);
```

Comment: [`std::array::try_from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.try_from_fn.html) would be ideal here, but unfortunately it is not stabilized

Comment: @kmdreko Yeah I know, really annoyed me I couldn't use that one. Do you have any ideas in the meantime?

Comment: By the way, `x.expect(return Err(...))` would return `Err` on every invocation, not only if `x` is `Err` or `None`. Use of `return` as an argument is pretty much always wrong. It is valid Rust because a `return` expression has type [`!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html), which can be implicitly converted to any type, but it almost certainly wouldn't do what you want.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 Does `WorkingCell` implement `Default` and/or `Copy`?

Comment: @cdhowie no but I can easily implement both, why do you ask?

Comment: @Pioneer_11 Because if you implement both there is a very simple solution to the problem, albeit at a slight reduction in performance. Otherwise, you either need a _huge_ reduction in performance or you need unsafe code. The unsafe code is not terribly awful, but it's also not exactly simple.

Comment: @cdhowie ok but what is that solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the type of element in your array implements `Default`, you can write a very simple implementation of the unstable standard library function `std::array::try_from_fn()` It is not nearly as optimized as `try_from_fn`, but requires no unsafe code:

```
fn array_try_from_fn<const N: usize, T, E, F>(mut f: F) -> Result<[T; N], E>
where
    T: Default,
    F: FnMut(usize) -> Result<T, E>,
{
    let mut arr = std::array::from_fn(|_| T::default());

    for i in 0..N {
        arr[i] = f(i)?;
    }

    Ok(arr)
}
```

This gives you the ergonomics of the standard library function, and allows you to easily swap this function out when `try_from_fn` is stabilized.

Comment: For more complex cases, where `T: !Copy`, but still `T: Default` (e.g. `Vec<T>`) one can use `std::array::from_fn(|_| T::default())` to create the initial array

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues I suppose that does work but it's far more complicated than what I was trying to do. I'd need to handle the errors from the inner loop in the outer loop and then again when creating the `UnsolvedSudoku` you're also straying into unstable code and taking a big performance hit. 

It does work but I can't see a single advantage of doing that over using building `Vec`s or `arrayvec`s and then calling `std::array::from_fn` on them

Comment: @Pioneer_11 He's only suggesting a minor change to my code that would make it possible to remove the `T:Copy` constraint. (In fact I just incorporated the suggestion into my answer.)

Comment: @cdhowie I understand that. I'm sure there are uses for this code, but it doesn't do what I asked for and if I were to extend so it did then it would be a poor solution. As it would require three layers of error handing for a single error, as well being inefficient. It's boilerplate on filling an array with 0's and swapping out values.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 It's pretty much the same in your case as `std::array::try_from_fn` which you mentioned in a comment on your question that you were annoyed you couldn't use it. So I'm very confused, as it seems to be your preferred solution, but you also have an objection to it at the same time?

Comment: @cdhowie that was somewhat poor phrasing on my part. It's annoying that `std::array::try_from_fn` isn't available, as it would be very useful in many cases. However, in this circumstance it would take a lot of error handling to do what I want it to do. Additionally the main reason to use `std::array::from_fn` is either that it is a faster or more terse way of creating an array both of those advantages are lost in this example.  I'm just looking for a way to just bail out and return an err if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 I mean, it's really not as big of a burden as you make it. The compiler is likely to inline all of this anyway, so the added layers shouldn't affect performance, either. Example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b9c886aac605d6c25671a143100881ea -- What about this example, which pretty much exactly matches the intent of your code, do you find unacceptable?